# function return a table in kdb/q

Tags: kdb

I'm new in kdb/q and I'm not familiar with kdb\q function, hope someone can help me. Here is the question:
I have a simple q function declared as the following:

```
func:{[x;y] x+y}
```

And `{[x;y] x+y}[3;4]` gives me the answer `7`. Everything works perfectly.

If I have a table `t` with two columns such as:

```
_x   _y
--------
3     4
2     5
6     2
...
```

Could I have a function in q such that compute `x+y` for each row of table`t`?
And my expected return would be something like:

```
res
---
7
7
8
...
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just pass the column names as parameters to the function:

```
q)tab:([]x:1 2 3;y:4 5 6)
q)func:{[x;y] x+y}
q)
q)select res:func[x;y]from tab
res
---
5
7
9
```

Alternatively you could use functional form to turn that query into a function:

```
q){?[x;();0b;enlist[`res]!enlist(`func;y;z)]}[tab;`x;`y]
res
---
5
7
9
```

Comment: That's aweson! Could you explain the second alternative to me>? I don't quite get it..

Comment: Its working with the functional form of selects, which is described in decent detail [on the wiki](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/funsql/). To see what functional form looks like for a query you can run `parse"select res:func[x;y]from tab"` which will output the 4 parameters required to make up the query.

Comment: Thanks so much! One more quick question: i have a function `func:{[id;time] select last synp from synp_t where instr_id = id, tp_time < time}` ; but when I run `func[8 1;05:01:06 05:06:01]`, it gives me 'length ERROR.. do you know where I was wrong..?

Answer (score 1):

Since `+` is overloaded to work with both atom and list , `res:func[x;y]` will work perfectly fine; however in cases when a dyadic function only accepts the arguments as atoms rather than lists then `each-both` will do the trick:

```
q)select res:func'[x;y] from tab  // using each-both func'[x;y]
res
---
5
7
9
```

e.g  To select as many charecters as `c` from column `s`

```
tab2:([] c:1 2 3;s:("123";"1234";"123456"))
q)update res:#'[c;s] from tab2  //func'[x;y]
c   s         res
-----------------------
1   "123"     enlist "1"
2   "1234"    "12"
3   "123456"  "123"
```